# Sql Server FILESTREAM Total File Size

Tags: sql-server, filestream

Is there a query that would get me the total file size of the files that are in the FILESTREAM folder on the disk?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following query will return the length in bytes of the `filestreamcolumn` column:

```
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(filestreamcolumn)) FROM filestreamtable;
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

One disadvantage of Remus' solution is that it will not include the old versions of files that are available for garbage collection. They will no longer be part of logical database, but will still consume disk space until the Filestream garbage collector deletes them.

Starting with Sql Server 2008 R2, you can query the size column of sys.database_files for an approximate size (i.e. disk space used) of a given filestream container.

Comment: I'm running SQL 2008 R2 SP0 CU8 and the size column is always 0 for filestream.

Answer (score 1):

```
use <DATABASE_NAME_HERE>
declare @table as nvarchar(100);
declare @columnName as nvarchar(100);
declare @query as nvarchar(500);
declare @sizeValue as nvarchar(100);
declare @generalValue as decimal(38);
declare @generalValueInMb as decimal(15,2);
set @generalValue = 0;

DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR FOR
(
SELECT DB_NAME()+'.**<schemaname_here>**.' + OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS [FullTableName], name As [ColumnName]
FROM sys.columns
WHERE is_filestream = 1 
)

Open tableCursor

fetch next from tableCursor into @table, @columnName

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
set @query = 'select @sizeValue = (select sum(Datalength('+@columnName+')) FROM ' + @table +')';
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@sizeValue int output', @sizeValue output;

if @sizeValue is not NULL
begin
set @generalValue = @generalValue + @sizeValue
end

fetch next from tableCursor into @table, @columnName
end

close tableCursor
deallocate tableCursor

select @generalValueInMb = round(@generalValue / 1024 / 1024, 2)

select @generalValueInMb
```

Note that you need to type schema name in proper place in above code.

Answer (score 0):

-- Improved version of AGR's answer with schema support

```
declare @table as nvarchar(100);
declare @columnName as nvarchar(100);
declare @query as nvarchar(500);
declare @sizeValue as nvarchar(100);
declare @generalValue as decimal(38);
declare @generalValueInMb as decimal(15,2);
set @generalValue = 0;

DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR FOR
(
SELECT DB_NAME()+'.'+ OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME((object_id)) +'.'+ OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS [FullTableName], name As [ColumnName]
FROM sys.columns
WHERE is_filestream = 1 
)

Open tableCursor

fetch next from tableCursor into @table, @columnName

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
set @query = 'select @sizeValue = (select sum(Datalength(['+@columnName+'])) FROM ' + @table +' with (nolock))';
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@sizeValue int output', @sizeValue output;

if @sizeValue is not NULL
begin
set @generalValue = @generalValue + @sizeValue
end

fetch next from tableCursor into @table, @columnName
end

close tableCursor
deallocate tableCursor

select @generalValueInMb = round(@generalValue / 1024 / 1024, 2)

select @generalValueInMb
```