# SQL Server Database Size

Tags: sql-server, database, size

From C# I am running the SQL query `EXEC sp_spaceused` to find the space used by a database.

I get only the space of the database and its log file. But I also need the FileStream size.

How can I also get the filestream size?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Sql Server FILESTREAM Total File Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086603/sql-server-filestream-total-file-size)

```
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(filestreamcolumn)) FROM filestreamtable;
```